# 3D Transform по окружности вокруг оси Х

Tags: css, html5, css3, анимация, svg

Я пытаюсь создать `CSS` анимацию, которая выглядит, как вращение вокруг картинки или другого объекта `div` вокруг оси "Х".

Мне удалось создать примерное представление о нем по адресу: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Kupe517/pen/zBKGev), но анимированные `div` не имеют эффекта вращения, который я ищу.

Я думаю, мне нужно добавить в какой-то элемент `rotateX ()`, чтобы преобразовать и добавить перспективу, но я просто не могу понять, какую нужно комбинацию. Я приложил примерный образ такой анимации, которую  пытаюсь получить.

Здесь мой текущий код анимации:

```
@keyframes moveBack { 
 0%{transform:translateY(0); z-index:10;}
 25%{transform:translateY(435px); z-index:10;}
 26%{z-index:0;}
 50%{transform:translateY(0) scale(.8); z-index:0;}
 75%{transform:translateY(-435px); z-index:0;}
 76%{z-index:10;}
 100%{transform:translateY(0); z-index:10;}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [3D Transform around circle on the X axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37929882/7394871) от участника  [@Kupe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1717833/kupe).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929882/3d-transform-around-circle-on-the-x-axis/37941155#37941155

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Здесь есть простая 3D-транзакция, которая выглядит так, как вы пытаетесь получить. Вопрос в том, что вы используете `translate` для перемещения, но ваша цель - вращать по оси `x`. Для запуска вращения, наведите курсор на див (прямоугольник):

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  width:300px; height:200px;
  margin:10% auto;
  perspective:500px;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
img{width:100%;}
p{
  position:absolute;
  left:250px; top:75px;
  width:80px; height:40px;
  margin:0; padding:5px 10px;
  background:gold;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translatez(110px);
  transition:transform 2s;
}
div:hover p{
  transform: rotateX(360deg) translatez(110px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg"/>
  <p>Hover the div</p>
</div>
```

Если вы хотите, вращающийся див, ориентировать всегда одной стороной к лицу пользователя, то вы можете добавить следующий поворот, после такой `translatez`:

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  width:300px; height:200px;
  margin:10% auto;
  perspective:500px;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
img{width:100%;}
p{
  position:absolute;
  left:250px; top:75px;
  width:80px; height:40px;
  margin:0; padding:5px 10px;
  background:gold;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translatez(130px) rotateX(0deg);
  transition:transform 5s;
}
div:hover p{
  transform: rotateX(360deg) translatez(130px) rotateX(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg"/>
  <p>Hover the div</p>
</div>
```

Это работает, потому что, когда вы выполняете цепочку преобразования свойств на одном и том же объявлении, последний выполняется по окончанию предыдущего из них. Система координат движется с предыдущими преобразованиями.

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [3D Transform around circle on the X axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37941155/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>